# How do you cause an expectation to halt execution in RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I want to test that a class receives a class-method call in RSpec:

```
describe MyObject do
  it "should create a new user" do 
    expect(User).to receive(:new)
    MyObject.new.doit
  end
end

class MyObject
  def doit
    u = User.new
    u.save
  end
end
```

The problem is that the expectation does not halt execution. It simply stubs the class method `.doit` and continues execution.

The effect of the  expectation is to ensure that `User.new` returns `nil`. So when we get to the next line which is `User.save` it then fails because there is no user object to call `.save` on.

I would like execution to halt as soon as the RSpec expectation has been satisfied - how can I do that?

**nb**

This is just an illustrative example - while an `expect to change` would work for User.new, it's not this actual code that I need to test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a great method for this [`and_call_original`](http://rspec.info/documentation/3.5/rspec-mocks/#Delegating_to_the_Original_Implementation):

```
expect(User).to receive(:new).and_call_original
```

Comment: you beauty zishe - this is perfect

Comment: Awesome, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

based on your test description, you're testing that a record was created, in those cases I would suggest you to do this:

```
expect {
  MyObject.new.doit
}.to change{User.count}
```

or if you want to make sure it only created one:

```
expect {
  MyObject.new.doit
}.to change{User.count}.by(1)
```

Comment: The example I chose was just an example. I agree with what you're saying  were I wanting to check that a user was created but I actually want to test a different method that can't be tested using this technique. I genuinely need to test that a class method is called